# почему моя прога зависает и как это исправить?

Tags: c

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)

{
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void priempackets(void * Pspisarguments);

typedef struct spisarg
 {
   struct sock
   {
   int nomersock;
 int packet_data[10000];
 int port;
 DWORD received_bytes;
 int fromLength;
   }sockets[4];
  int maximum_packet_sizeS;
  struct sockaddr_in from,fromCommand,address[];
  int lineS;
  int schetlineS;
  int parityS;
  struct WAVHEADER
  {
  // WAV-формат начинается с RIFF-заголовка:

// Содержит символы "RIFF" в ASCII кодировке
// (0x52494646 в big-endian представлении)
char chunkId[3];

// 36 + subchunk2Size, или более точно:
// 4 + (8 + subchunk1Size) + (8 + subchunk2Size)
// Это оставшийся размер цепочки, начиная с этой позиции.
// Иначе говоря, это размер файла - 8, то есть,
// исключены поля chunkId и chunkSize.
unsigned long chunkSize;

// Содержит символы "WAVE"
// (0x57415645 в big-endian представлении)
char format[3];

// Формат "WAVE" состоит из двух подцепочек: "fmt " и "data":
// Подцепочка "fmt " описывает формат звуковых данных:

// Содержит символы "fmt "
// (0x666d7420 в big-endian представлении)
char subchunk1Id[3];

// 16 для формата PCM.
// Это оставшийся размер подцепочки, начиная с этой позиции.
unsigned long subchunk1Size;

// Аудио формат, полный список можно получить здесь http://audiocoding.ru/wav_formats.txt
// Для PCM = 1 (то есть, Линейное квантование).
// Значения, отличающиеся от 1, обозначают некоторый формат сжатия.
unsigned short audioFormat;

// Количество каналов. Моно = 1, Стерео = 2 и т.д.
unsigned short numChannels;

// Частота дискретизации. 8000 Гц, 44100 Гц и т.д.
unsigned long sampleRate;

// sampleRate * numChannels * bitsPerSample/8
unsigned long byteRate;

// numChannels * bitsPerSample/8
// Количество байт для одного сэмпла, включая все каналы.
unsigned short blockAlign;

// Так называемая "глубиная" или точность звучания. 8 бит, 16 бит и т.д.
unsigned short bitsPerSample;

// Подцепочка "data" содержит аудио-данные и их размер.

// Содержит символы "data"
// (0x64617461 в big-endian представлении)
char subchunk2Id[3];

// numSamples * numChannels * bitsPerSample/8
// Количество байт в области данных.
unsigned long subchunk2Size;

// Далее следуют непосредственно Wav данные.
  }wavhead;
 }spisarguments;


void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

 spisarguments Farguments;

 Farguments.wavhead.chunkId[0] = 'R';
 Farguments.wavhead.chunkId[1] = 'I';
 Farguments.wavhead.chunkId[2] = 'F';
 Farguments.wavhead.chunkId[3] = 'F';
 Farguments.wavhead.chunkSize = 35;//КОЛ-во байт всего файла
 Farguments.wavhead.format[0] = 'W';
 Farguments.wavhead.format[1] = 'A';
 Farguments.wavhead.format[2] = 'V';
 Farguments.wavhead.format[3] = 'E';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk1Id[0] = 'f';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk1Id[1] = 'm';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk1Id[2] = 't';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk1Id[3] = ' ';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk1Size = 16; // для PCM
 Farguments.wavhead.audioFormat = 1;// PCM
 Farguments.wavhead.numChannels = 1;//моно
 Farguments.wavhead.sampleRate =  44100;
 Farguments.wavhead.byteRate = 44100;
 Farguments.wavhead.blockAlign = 2; //nBlockAlign = (nChannels * wBitsPerSample) / 8
 Farguments.wavhead.bitsPerSample = 16;
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk2Id[0] = 'd';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk2Id[1] = 'a';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk2Id[2] = 't';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk2Id[3] = 'a';
 Farguments.wavhead.subchunk2Size =0;// КОЛ-во байт в области данных

 unsigned int packet_data[10000];
 unsigned int packet_data1[10000];

 WSADATA wsaData;

if (WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsaData))
{
    printf ("winsock not bi initialized !\n");
    WSACleanup();
}

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  Farguments.sockets[i].nomersock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if ( Farguments.sockets[i].nomersock<= 0)
{
    printf( "failed to create socket\n" );
}
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
Farguments.address[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
Farguments.address[i].sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
Farguments.address[i].sin_port = htons(12340+i);
if ( bind( Farguments.sockets[i].nomersock, (const sockaddr*) &Farguments.address[i], sizeof(sockaddr_in) ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "failed to bind socket\n" );

}
 }

 Farguments.fromCommand.sin_family = AF_INET;

 DWORD nonBlocking = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    if ( ioctlsocket( Farguments.sockets[i].nomersock, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking ) != 0 )
    {
        printf( "failed to set non-blocking socket\n" );
    }
 }


    Farguments.lineS =0;
    Farguments.schetlineS = 0;
 Farguments.maximum_packet_sizeS= sizeof(1500);
///-------------------------------------------------------------------------


 spisarg *Pspisarguments;
 Pspisarguments = &Farguments;


  _beginthread( priempackets, 0, (void *) Pspisarguments);
 ///------------------------------------------------------------------------


 }
 //-----------------ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ-------------------------------------------
 void priempackets(void * Pspisarguments)
 {
 struct txtfile
 {
 char time_start[40];
 char time_end[40];
 char line[10];
 char priority[15];
 char source_IP[40];
 char fileName[40];
 }txtFileWAV;

 strcpy(txtFileWAV.time_start, "time start: ");
 strcpy(txtFileWAV.time_end, "time end: ");
 strcpy(txtFileWAV.line, "line: ");
 strcpy(txtFileWAV.priority, "priority: ");
 strcpy(txtFileWAV.source_IP, "source IP: ");
 strcpy(txtFileWAV.fileName, "fileName: ");

 unsigned int from_address = 0;
    unsigned int from_port = 0;
     in_addr fromIP;
     char lineCOM[1];
     char parityCOM[1];
 ///------------------------------------------------------------------------

  while(true)
  {
  char *paket = new char [11];
    ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].received_bytes =
    recvfrom( ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].nomersock, (char*)paket,
     ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->maximum_packet_sizeS,
     0, (sockaddr*)&((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->from,
     &((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].fromLength );

   if (strncmp("CALL",paket,4)==0)
   {

memcpy(&fromIP,paket+4,4);

memcpy(lineCOM,paket+8,1);
memcpy(parityCOM,paket+10,1);
((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS = int (lineCOM);
((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->parityS = int (parityCOM);
    paket = new char [8];
    strcpy(paket,"ACK");

    memcpy(paket+3,&fromIP,4);
    memcpy(paket+7,lineCOM,1);
    sendto(((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].nomersock, (char*)paket, ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->maximum_packet_sizeS,
    0,(SOCKADDR *) & ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->fromCommand, sizeof (((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->fromCommand));


   char *buf;
 time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time( &rawtime );                // получить текущую дату, выраженную в секундах
timeinfo = localtime( &rawtime );
buf = asctime(timeinfo);
strcat(txtFileWAV.time_start, buf);

///-------------------------------------------------------------------------

int schetchik =0;


FILE* WAV;
 FILE* TXT;
WAV=fopen("newWAV.wav" , "wb");


strcat(txtFileWAV.line, lineCOM);
strcat(txtFileWAV.priority, parityCOM);


while ( true )
{
    char *paket = new char [8];
    recvfrom( ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].nomersock, (char*)paket,
    ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->maximum_packet_sizeS,
    0, (sockaddr*)&((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->from,
    &((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[4].fromLength );

   if (strncmp("BYE",paket,3)==0)
   {

    break;
   }


   delete [] paket;

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *paketZ = new int [500];


   ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS].received_bytes=
   recvfrom( ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS].nomersock,
   (char*)paketZ, ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->maximum_packet_sizeS,
   0, (sockaddr*)&((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->from,
    &((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS].fromLength );




    for(unsigned int i=0+schetchik;
    i<(((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS].received_bytes-12)+schetchik;i++)
    {
      fwrite(&paketZ[i+13], sizeof (paketZ[i+13]), 1 , WAV );
    }
    schetchik = schetchik+
    (((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->sockets[((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->lineS].received_bytes-12);

    ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->wavhead.chunkSize = 35+schetchik;
    ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->wavhead.subchunk2Size = schetchik;
    fseek(WAV, (44+schetchik), 0);


    delete [] paketZ;

    from_address = ntohl( ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->from.sin_addr.s_addr );
    from_port = ntohs( ((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->from.sin_port );


   }


   string str;
 char bufchar = char (from_address);
  char *pchar;
   pchar = &bufchar;

  str = bufchar;


 buf = new char [str.length()];
buf = pchar;
strcat(txtFileWAV.source_IP, buf);

buf = new char [strlen("newWAV.txt")];
strcat(txtFileWAV.fileName, buf);

fseek(WAV, 0L, 0);
fwrite(&(((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->wavhead), sizeof (((spisarg *)Pspisarguments)->wavhead), 1 , WAV );


fclose(WAV);


timeinfo = localtime( &rawtime );

buf = asctime(timeinfo);
strcat(txtFileWAV.time_end, buf);
TXT = fopen("newWAVTXT.txt" , "wb");
fwrite(&txtFileWAV, sizeof (txtFileWAV), 1 , TXT );
fclose(TXT);


  }


 }

}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

В общем есть функция `void priempackets(void * Pspisarguments)`которая находится в кнопке  `void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)`. Эта функция вызывается через `_beginthread( priempackets, 0, (void *) Pspisarguments);`благодаря чему, создаётся новый процесс с этой функцией. В ней есть 2 `while`, 1 бесконечный(главный) и 1 с `break`. Скорее всего зависает именно из за них, но почему? Ведь я эти вайлы использую в другом процессе, а не в главном. И как исправить мне эту проблему, если мне нужно постоянно принимать пакеты?

Comment: У вас там UB несколько раз. Для начала выучите, чем длина области памяти отличается от смещения к последнему элементу в ней.

Comment: что значит UB и для чего мне нужно учить эту область памяти и смещение?

Comment: Я за вас делать домашнее задание не очень рвусь. Есть поисковики, есть книги...

Comment: прикольно, я понял...